# Working with python, do I need to write down AST to evaluate a boolean function?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, abstract-syntax-tree, boolean-expression, brackets

I am working on a project, one part of it is to generate a truth table for a given boolean expression ( such as: (A NOT B) NOR (C OR D)). I could not find a built in bitwise operator for NOR gate, so I wrote a code of my own for it, which works good with simple expressions. But if brackets are introduced for unambiguity and false results, the code does a terrible job. [for example, for the expression mentioned above, it gives an output of (a~b~()|()c|d)]
Here is the code snippet:

```
 # to replace NOR gate with bitwise NOR operation of ~(var_a | var_b)
  for m in range(0,len(expression)):
   v=len(expression)
   for v in range(0,len(expression)):
     if (expression[v]=="!"):
        prev='~(' + expression[v-1]
        nextt=expression[v+1]+')'
        replacement= prev + "|" + nextt
        leftear= expression[:v-1]
        rightear=expression[v+2:]
        print('left right ears:',leftear,rightear)
        expression= leftear+replacement+rightear
        
  print('expression refined= X= ',expression)
```

The only solution that I found on google was to write a parse tree (which python says that, it has been deprecated so we are recommended to use AST). I am a total beginner and search out a little bit about parse trees, but I wanted to ask:
**1)Is the AST or parsers the only way to do it?  Are there any built in functions for it in python?**
**2) Whats the better way of handeling NOR gate ?**

Comment: The solution you found means that instead of calculating the result of the expression while you traverse it, you first parse it into an object and continue working on that parsed object. This is a great way of handling your brackets. Of course you can also handle brackets directly when traversing your input but this will probably result in spaghetti code

Comment: The `ast` module can parse Python code. If the only non-Python syntax is `NOR`, you can try to extend Python syntax a little. Which syntax are you required to parse? Just one example `(A NOT B) NOR (C OR D))` doesn't show it all. Are you required to parse `XOR`? Any Python expression, including arithmetic? Also, what operator precedence should you use (e.g. how to parse `NOT A AND B`)? The answer to these questions will affect the decision of whether or not to use `ast`. Also, what does `A NOT B` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be bitwise? Judging from your example, you could just use the normal Boolean operators.

It's true there is no `nor` in Python, but you can easily translate it, because `E NOR F` equals `NOT E AND NOT F`, and `not` and `and` are available in Python.

For example:

```py
from itertools import product

print('  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  | (A AND NOT B) NOR (C OR D)')
print('---------------------------------------------------')

for a, b, c, d in product((True, False), repeat=4):
    result = not (a and not b) and not (c or d)
    print('{:^5}|{:^5}|{:^5}|{:^5}|{:^34}'.format(a, b, c, d, result))
```

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  | (A AND NOT B) NOR (C OR D)
---------------------------------------------------
  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |                0                 
  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |                0                 
  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |                0                 
  1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |                1                 
  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |                0                 
  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |                0                 
  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |                0                 
  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |                0                 
  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |                0                 
  0  |  1  |  1  |  0  |                0                 
  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |                0                 
  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |                1                 
  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |                0                 
  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |                0                 
  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |                0                 
  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |                1
```

Comment: Consider using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to avoid the deep nested loops.

Comment: Oh yeah I don't need to use bitwise, its just increasng lines of code, Thank you 
But, you translated the NOR gate by yourself. Thats exactly my problem. I want my program to take input from user and replace NOR via function, and like, in (A AND B) NOR (C OR D), NOR gate is in between two bracket terms and NORs the results of its neighbouring calculations. So I can't replace it directly. In my code, I have translated the NOR gate into NOT (A or B) as well but if there're backets around, it can't find the variables to NOR.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can also use prefix notation, you might be able to use the
`sympy` library.

Below is a small program that demonstrates using it for
a sample expression derived from your question, with some code at the
end to generate the truth table for the expression using the `satisfiable`
function, which generates all possible models for the logic expression.

```
import itertools
from sympy import *
from sympy.logic import simplify_logic
from sympy.logic.inference import satisfiable

my_names = 'ABCD'
A,B,C,D = symbols(','.join(my_names))
e1 = Nor(Nor(A, B), Or(C, D))
e2 = ~(~(A | B) | (C | D))
print('e1 and e2 are same:', e1 == e2)
print(simplify_logic(e1))
my_symbols = sorted(e1.atoms(Symbol), key=lambda x: x.name)
print('Set of symbols used:', my_symbols)
models = satisfiable(e1, all_models=True)
sat_mods = []
for m in models:
    sat_mods.append(dict(sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].name)))
truth_tab = []
for c in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=4):
    model = dict(zip(my_symbols, c))
    truth_tab.append((model, model in sat_mods))
print(truth_tab)
```

Output:

```
# e1 and e2 are same: True
# ~C & ~D & (A | B)
# Set of symbols used: [A, B, C, D]
# [({A: True, B: True, C: True, D: True}, False),
#  ({A: True, B: True, C: True, D: False}, False),
# ...
```